# Windows will not allow me to set MKV files to open in MPC?

Tags: windows-7, file-association, media-player-classic

When I go to open with, click browse, and select the MPC-HC exe, windows does not add it to the open with list, instead it just totally ignores it.  I wasn't having this issue until I reinstalled it, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

have you gone to `control panel - default programs - set associations` to associate the filetype with the program?

Comment: Yes, it brings up the same dialog box, http://i.imgur.com/YeomHDS.png, when I click browse, select mpc-hc64.exe, press OK, then it does not add it to the list or throw any warnings whatsoever, and remains identical to http://i.imgur.com/YeomHDS.png